# Clearing :Date field in Realm when updating object

Tags: swift, realm

I have the following data model

```
@objc dynamic var uid = UUID().uuidString;
@objc dynamic var completed: Bool = false;
@objc dynamic var dateCompleted: Date?;
```

When I create a new object it has `nil` for the `dateCompleted`, then when the user completes the task I try to update the object with `primaryKey (uid)` like so

```
let query = realm.objects(Tasks.self).filter("uid = %@", id).first!;
if query.completed == false {
    var date = Date();
} else {
    var date: Date = nil
}

let wayUpdate = ["uid": id, "completed": !query.completed, "dateCompleted": date] as [String : Any]

do {
    try realm.write {
        realm.create(WaysData.self, value: wayUpdate, update: true)
    }
} catch {
    print("Error adding update to experience! \(error)");
}
```

I get the following error `Cannot convert value of type 'String' to specified type 'Date'` in the `else block`.

My question is - is there a way to clear the date when updating completion to false, or should I just leave `dateCompleted` as `Date()` each time the user completes/uncompletes/completes the task and just do a check on the `completed: Bool` value whenever I want to update the completion button's label to "Complete" or "Revive"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to update a single property of your `Object` subclass instance, don't call `create`, simply modify that single property in a write transaction.

```
do {
    try realm.write {
        query.dateCompleted = query.completed ? nil : Date()
    }
} catch {
    print("Error adding update to experience! \(error)")
}
```

You should also use the primary key to retrieve the object, don't filter the query.

```
let query = realm.object(ofType: Tasks.self,forPrimaryKey: id)
```

Unrelated to your issue, but you shouldn't use `;` at the end of your lines in Swift, this is not Objective-C.

Comment: Thank you for the great extra tips @Dávid!